# Loop in object creation and declaration with annotations

Tags: modelica, dymola

I need to use a loop to create multiple objects in my model declaration. 
For loops do not seem to work outside an "equation" or an "algorithm" block.
I need to declare my objects in the beggining of the Model.
I also need to add different annotation to each object so that the location of each object differs.

As a result i want to create a tank consisting of cellConst subparts (found in Thermocycle package).

I already tried to do so by using the following code:

```
model MyTank

CellConst [N] cellConstArray = {
CellConst (
Ai=0.53, 
Ac=0.88, 
Mdotnom=1, 
L=0.25, Discretization=ThermoCycle.Functions.Enumerations.Discretizations.upwind_AllowFlowReversal, Vi=0.030, Tstart=293.15)
annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-14,22},{-8,28}})))
for i in 1:N
};

end MyTank;
```

I also tried a simple loop

```
model MyTank

for i in 1:N loop
end for;

end MyTank;
```

Though None of these two approaches worked.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do things slightly differently in Modelica: you add modifiers to each element of the vector like this:

```
model MyTank

CellConst [N] cellConstArray(each Ai=0.53, 
 each Ac=0.88, 
 each Mdotnom=1, 
 each L=0.25, 
 each Discretization=ThermoCycle.Functions.Enumerations.Discretizations.upwind_AllowFlowReversal, 
 Vi = fill(0.030, N), // Just to show you can use an array here
 each Tstart=293.15)
);
end MyTank;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! 
Do you have any idea on how to also add annotation with different coordinates for each element of the array so that i can see them all in the Diagram View ?

Comment: Unfortunately The following displays only one box though i want one box for each element of the array.



`
CellConst [N] cellConstArray(
    each Ai=0.53,
    each Ac=0.88,
    each Mdotnom=1,
    each L=0.25,    Discretization=ThermoCycle.Functions.Enumerations.Discretizations.upwind_AllowFlowReversal,
    each Vi=0.030,
    each Tstart=293.15)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-14,-6},{-8,0}})));
`

Comment: If you want multiple entries in the graphics I believe you need to create one entry for each (so it's no longer an array but rather multiple variables).